# How to display/print a file while building a docker image

Tags: docker

Folks, I am building a Docker image from a Dockerfile I am stuck on a silly position where I am updating a yaml file using sed.

```
RUN sed -i -e "s@\$REPLACEMENT_TAG@$PM_SERVER_DOCKER_TAG@" /qa.yaml
```

After this step I need to show the yaml file on the output console while building the docker image but I am not able to show it via echo command. Could someone help me with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `cat` not `echo`. `echo` will print the name of a file. `cat` displays its contents.

```
RUN cat /qa.yaml
```

As per [spankmaster79](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131664/spankmaster79) in the comments, with the [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/) backend you will also need `--progress=plain` for output. Thus, since you are supposedly debugging, you will need to do something similar to:

```
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain -t containername .
```

Comment: this works great, except that it does not when layer is cached. Is there any way to either prevent layer from caching, or print it even though cached?

Comment: You can use `--no-cache` argument when you build your image

Comment: sorry, but for me this doesn't work. Tried with no-cache to cat /etc/apt/sources.list after adding a source but nothing is in the output

Comment: EDIT: since we're on buildkit now adding --progress=plain is needed as well for output

Answer (score 5):

+1 for 'cat' but, if you still want to use echo you can use as given below

```
RUN echo "$(<filename)"
```

Comment: Why would someone want to do that?